# Referencing deleted function when using unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I have the following class definition:

```
class InterpolatedSpreadConnector
{
public:
    ~InterpolatedSpreadConnector() = default;
    GPUImage* operator()() override;

    GPUImage* AncestorReducedConnectivity = nullptr;
    GPUImage* OffspringReducedConnectivity = nullptr;
};
```

, which, when used in the declaration `auto connector = InterpolatedSpreadConnector();` works just fine. I want to change those raw pointers to `unique_ptr`s, however.

Including `memory` and replacing the raw pointers with `std::unique_ptr<GPUImage>` members in the definition gives me an `attempting to reference deleted function` error on the `InterpolatedSpreadConnector` copy constructor. Strangely, the error goes away if I replace the `unique_ptr` with a `shared_ptr`.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: `unique` means not copyable or assignable. But better post a [mcve].

Comment: Have a read of this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

Comment: I thought there was something like copy elision (?) which automatically skipped the copy construction and assumed normal construction in cases like these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this code to work, prior to C++17, you will need to define a move-constructor for your class. This could be as simple as:

```
 InterpolatedSpreadConnector(InterpolatedSpreadConnector &&) = default;
```

Your user-defined destructor means that implicit generation of the move-constructor is suppressed.

And with no move-constructor, a copy/move operation falls back to the copy-constructor, which causes the compilation error since the implicitly-generated copy-constructor is deleted because `unique_ptr` has a deleted copy-constructor.

---

In C++14 and earlier, `auto x = X();` conceptually means that we create a temporary `X` and then copy/move-construct `x` from the temporary and destroy the temporary.  The compiler is allowed to [elide](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) the temporary but the correct constructors for that procedure must still exist.

However in C++17, `auto x = X();` will be defined to mean the same as `X x{};`.

So your code will work in C++17, although it is a good idea to define the move-constructor anyway; or preferably remove the destructor definition (see [Rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).

Comment: I see. I thought copy elision automatically skipped the copy construction and assumed normal construction in cases like these.

Comment: @KristianD'Amato It does, but the constructors that would be used if copy elision didn't happen, must exist and be accessible.  The rationale is that if a compiler decides to do or not to do copy elision, the program should not suddenly fail to compile depending on that choice.